# Can this be done in one line with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use the AddRange method on my context. The only thing that changes in the object is the key

```
 foreach (var key in keysToAdd)
        {
            var myObject = new myObject
            {
                Key = key,
                GroupKey = request.GroupKey,
                ResourceKey = request.ResourceKey
            };
            //instead of iterating I want to use AddRange()
            _context.MyObject.Add(myObject);
        }
```

Is it possible not to iterate over the keysToAdd and just create an object for each key?

Comment: what is `_context.MyObject`?

Comment: Changing means updating, i see you are adding not changing ?

Comment: Does AddRange not exist on that object, or are you asking how to do it with AddRange?

Comment: @Grundy - `Enumerable.Aggregate` indeed can add... Is it "true LINQ"? - I'd say yes as part of map/reduce pair.

Comment: `_context.MyObject.AddRange(keysToAdd.Select(key=> new myObject{...}));`

Comment: @Grundy that is my database context

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am trying to create the list of objects and save them in one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = keysToAdd.Select(r=> new myObject
                    {
                      Key = r, 
                      GroupKey = request.GroupKey,
                      ResourceKey = request.ResourceKey
                    }).ToList();
```

Later you can do

```
_context.MyObject.AddRange(list);
```

Or you can do that in one statement like:

```
_context.MyObject.AddRange(keysToAdd.Select(r=> new myObject
                        {
                          Key = r,
                          GroupKey = request.GroupKey,
                          ResourceKey = request.ResourceKey
                        }));
```

Comment: If `_context.MyObject` is a `List`

Comment: @Jonny, the OP has "I want to use AddRange()", so I believe it is a list.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> Is it possible not to iterate over the keysToAdd and just create an object for each key?

No it's not, a projection (i.e. all the answers using `.Select(...)`) is still effectively *iterating* the collection so one way or another this has to be done. However, there is a performance difference (really depending on how big your collection is) for using `AddRange` over `Add` but without proper benchmarks you won't know if it's even going to make a difference.

Sometimes LINQ can be detrimental to performance, it's usually worth investigating this before you decide to rewrite code. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could shorten it like this...

```
 keysToAdd.ToList().ForEach(key => _context.MyObject.Add(new myObject(...));
```

but you have to iterate over the collection either way.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% LINQ, but `List<T>` has a `ForEach` method which you could use:

```
keysToAdd
    .Select(k => new myObject{ Key = k, GroupKey = request.GroupKey, ResourceKey = request.ResourceKey })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => _context.MyObject.Add(x));
```

Or that last line can actually be shortened to:

```
    .ForEach(_context.MyObject.Add);
```

Comment: read this first http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @slippyr4 Agreed, not always an appropriate pattern. IMO, it works here, but like Eric says, it does break the functional-style rules of LINQ, so it may not be a good habit to pick up.

Comment: I agree, but felt it useful to post here. When you first learn about ForEach, it's tempting to think of all the powerful things you might do with it. Everyone should read that article and think about it, first, I think.